# Python practice game, issue with switching between while loops

Tags: python, python-3.7

I want these while loops on line 21 - 34 to alternate (one ends the next one begins) but one simply stops and the next one doesn't run.

```
def update(self):
    mv_p = False
    while not mv_p:
        self.rect.x -= 5
        if self.rect.left > width - 750:
            mv_p = True
            return mv_p
            break

    while mv_p:
        self.rect.y += 5
        if self.rect.right < width - 750:
            mv_p = False
            return mv_p
            break
```

Comment: `return` exits your function completely, returning `mv_p`.  If you want it to continue to next loop, you don't need neither `return` nor in fact `break` - your first loop will terminate automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Calling return inside of a loop will break function/method execution and return value to the caller.

So, as soon as the first loop returns `mv_p`, your method call is over.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to alternate (first loop, second loop, first loop, second loop, etc), you should nest them inside another loop.

```
def update(self):
    mv_p = False
    while True:
        while not mv_p:
            self.rect.x -= 5
            if self.rect.left > width - 750:
                mv_p = True
                break

        while mv_p:
            self.rect.y += 5
            if self.rect.right < width - 750:
                mv_p = False
                break

        #need to draw on the screen here or nothing will be shown
        #add condition to exit the function, adding for example a return
        #inside af if, otherwise this will be an infinite loop.
```

If instead you just want first loop, second loop and exit no need to nest them, just remove the `return` calls from your function.

Comment: I tried this and my program opens with a black screen and is stuck loading.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that you need to draw the rect inside the loop. Added a comment where the drawing should occurr. Otherwise even in the rects are updated nothing is shown on the screen.